# how to put a second in the time in mssql

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to show the second of the time too, not only the hours and minutes. how can i put a seconds of a time in sql code?

here's select statement:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME),100)AS Currtime
```

here's the result:

```
1:48PM
```

expected format:

```
1:48:30 PM
```

Comment: How about `109`, instead of `100`?

Comment: What is your expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(), 109),8) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE()), 2) AS Currtime
```

Result:

```
11:34:41 AM
```

Comment: @Emz1402 - Add the expected result format in question

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  SELECT CONVERT(Varchar(10), GETDATE(),108)As CurrentTime;
```

or

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0),GETDATE()) AS CurrentTime;
```

Result:

> 10:35:04